# How to trigger a scheduled task on different times, according to a specific timestamp

Tags: node.js, push-notification, triggers, cron, eventtrigger

I have different times stored in my DB, let us say, 1)25 Sep 07:00, 2)26 Sep 14:00, 3)27 Sep 18:00. Now I want to trigger a notification at different times. 1)One day before, 2)One hour before, 3)At the time.
Ex.Notification should trigger at 1)24 Sep 07:00, 2)25 Sep 06:00, 3)25 Sep 07:00, 4)25 Sep 14:00, 5)26 Sep 13:00, 6)26 Sep 14:00, 7)26 Sep 18:00, 8)27 Sep 17:00, 9)27 Sep 18:00.

I was thinking about cron, But also confused when should I run the cron, At which time interval.

I expect notification trigger 1)One day before, 2)One hour before, 3)At the time.

Comment: I would say you go with the cronjob that will run once every hour. The function executed by the cronjob should compare the timestamps in your database against the current timestamp and it will send notification in case of the three different conditions you mentioned. You will need also a new column with a boolean type that serves to avoid sending the same notification type twice.

Comment: @user007 Thanks for reply, cron is good option, but I think 1 hour is quit long, I was thinking every 5 min. or 15 min., because all the times are perfectly unique. It could be 18:00, 18:06, 18:55 etc.

Comment: you can of course adjust the frequency of executing the cronjob as you want. It depends really which service are you using, since the higher frequency the more you should pay (if it's a payable service).

Comment: Actually I am not worried about payment cost, I am worried about load on server, If I run cron every 15 min. or 5 min. (which will give more accurate outcome).

Comment: well ! you will have more accuray with the 5 min option. Try it out and see what results you will have.You may take under consideration that the cronjob even if it runs every 5 mins it won't sometimes run EXACTLY before 1 day, 1 hour and at the time, that of course in case your dates in your DB is dynamic and could be 14:01 for example. You will have than to set a threshold of 5 min, like send notification when before an 55mins, 1hour or 1hour and 5mins